# Reading CSS3 Values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to read CSS3 values with jQuery? I've tried just using:

`var test = $("#container").css("transition") // there, normal selector.`

but I get "null" as the value, even though it's actually `margin-left .5s`. If I try `-webkit-transition` instead of `transition` (since I'm testing in Chrome), it doesn't give me any value.

If there's not a way to do this yet, that's alright, but I figured it was working asking. Maybe there's a plugin or something that I can use to do this? I basically need to change the `transition` after a certain number of slides and then change it back.

Comment: Your selector is peculiar. You should just do $("#container") since IDs have to be unique per page.

Comment: Actually, I believe you can nest `id`s (by putting elements inside of elements.)

Comment: Sure, you can nest them, but it is pointless to use a jQuery selector in this fashion.

Comment: Maybe it's just further specifying the CSS selector?

Comment: @summea Granted, but when using jQuery to select elements multiple id's as a selector is ***not necessary***. In `CSS` it'd make more sense - as it would add specificity to the definition...

Comment: It is pointless to know if #container is a child of #slideshow because there is only one #container allowed on the page...

Comment: It doesn't make sense. `id` is unique.

Comment: Selectors are read right-to-left so `#container` is found first, but since it's unique there is no need to specify which `#container` you are looking for, so you can remove `#slideshow` from the selection.

Comment: I see what you are saying; just trying to suss out why it was used in that way in the example given.  Perhaps it was being used as a designer/programmer reference to where that element is in the layout of the page...  (i.e. this _container_ is part of the _slideshow_...)

Comment: Point's not the selector, I can easily change that, I was just using it that way for testing...It never causes any problems for me, I just like doing it that way so I can more easily see where things are happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transition` is a shorthand property; it stands in for `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`, and `transition-delay`.

jQuery's `.css` doesn't support getting the value of shorthand CSS properties, so you have to get each constituent part separately.

Something like

```
$('#container').css('-webkit-transition-property')
```

would give you just the `margin-left` part, for example.

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that. I think this is the method I'll end up using, assuming I can get it to work. This really simplifies my script, got absolutely no user set variables now :)

Answer (score 1):

Does plain JS work?

```
document.getElementById('container').style.webkitTransition
// or
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('container')).webkitTransition
```

(Whether it works or not, it's over 500 times more efficient than the jQuery)

Comment: `over 500 times`? Here's a JSPerf I made to demonstrate the difference between using `.css()` (jQuery) and `element.style...` (standard JS): http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-element-style (more like 3-4 times faster).

Comment: I'm mostly going by the number of operations required to do the same thing. Even the most basic operation in jQuery takes over two hundred commands when the same can be done in just three lines of JS.

Comment: The point I was making is that saying `it's over 500 times more efficient than the jQuery` is not correct. `68%` slower corresponds to about four times slower, not five-hundred times (that's an error of like 99%). If you mean `500%` (or five times), that's different, but please update your answer to reflect that fact.

Comment: Possibely, but I am using all the vendor prefixes, so I'm not sure if that'll work or not. I'll definitely try it though.

Comment: I realised that after my reply, so I changed it. It still proves the point that regular JS is overall much faster than jQuery. Sure, jQuery can make you "write less to do more", but at that cost I'd rather write my own code.

Comment: @Rev don't use all the vender prefixes, just figure-out which one you need for the current browser: `var venderPrefix = ($.browser.webkit) ? 'Webkit' : ($.browser.mozilla) ? 'Moz' : ($.browser.msie) ? 'Ms' : ($.browser.opera) ? 'O' : '';`

Comment: Ah, didn't know that each of them actually had a unique bit of JS already, I guess that makes sense. What I meant was that I wasn't sure if I would be able to read/change each value with that, but it looks like this should work. I'll try it out when I get off work in a few hours.

Comment: @Rev Browser support is OK, but you'll miss-out on IE8 and older when using `getComputedStyle`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: That's fine, I have a jQuery fallback for the animations if the browser doesn't support transitions anyway.